# Can I run a front end client and a database without a server?

Tags: php, node.js, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The questing my sound stupid and I know it is. From what I know to connect the front end client and a database we need a server in the middle. We bought a web hosting service and in the package we have ASP, ASP.NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.5 and 4.7, MVC 5.0 ve .NET CORE 3.1.3 support. As well as a Mysql database. What confused me is they offer no support for node.js and PHP for back end servers in this package. So I'm left assuming I can use a database without a server. Is that possible?

Comment: You need a backend language to extract data from the database and pass it to the frontend. Looks like you got a Windows Hosting without PHP support.

Comment: Can windows hosting connect to their database, extract data and pass it to the front end? can I add any kind of logic to it?

Comment: You need a backend language. So either you use Asp.net as provided by your hosting or you ask them to install PHP if possible, you you check for any other language you can use. But you still need a Backend Language and a Web Server to interact with your frontend code.

Comment: You can of course connect to the database directly from the frontend. But that means you also have to give full credential to the database access, and in some cases, the full access to your host, to your frontend client, which is extremely dangerous and any security officer will ban this idea at first sight.

Comment: `Can windows hosting connect to their database, extract data and pass it to the front end`...yes of course. It's just another operating system, and has some different programming languages and frameworks available on it. (PHP does run on Windows but most hosting companies offer it on Linux packages only, mainly because Linux hosting is cheaper).

Comment: @momomo Windows hosting should be support for PHP too. You may need to ask your hosting provider first. If you need pure PHP, you can always go with Linux hosting. But, my windows provider offer both support for ASP and PHP.